# PCL profile conflict

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

I need to create a class library to be used in my Xamarin and ASP.NET MVC projects. But I'm beating my head trying to make this work.
The last thing I've done was to create a PCL for Xamarin (using VS template) build and add it to my project, but it doesn't matter, it always says the same thing:

`You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

I've checked both csprojs (for my lib and xamarin project) and they all target profile111.

PS: I know this "should" work because a lot of libraries do that. One example is `Portable.DataAnnotations` that I'm referencing in both projects.

**EDIT:**

What I've tried:

- Profile24, Profile111 and Profile259

What am I missing here?

Test project URL: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55538840394777983398

Comment: What exactly is your PCL profile?

Comment: @MihaMarkic sorry, it's .Net framework profile http://danrigby.com/2014/05/14/supported-pcl-profiles-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2/